# WildFly - create app with long running application

Tags: java, wildfly

I am new to JavaEE and am trying to create a WAR containing an application that performs a task every 30 minutes (and is started when the app is deployed), and a servlet that will allow a client to connect and get status information, using WildFly.

Is this possible? If so, how do I get WildFly to start the long running process, and how do I get it to inject that object into the servlet?

The long running application is in a class ProcessData() which uses ScheduledExecutorService to spawn a thread on a schedule to perform data management tasks, and has a getStatus() method returning a string about the processing.

This is the servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/procStat")
public class processorServlet extends HTTPServlet {
  @Inject
  ProcessData processData;

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
    writer.println("<p>" + processData.getStatus() + "</p>");
    writer.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's absolutely possible. You're probably thinking about using EJBs when you mention injecting the object into the servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need to inject it? Can you initialize it and use it with static method or something? Here is my example for that:

```
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
    ProcessData processData;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
   {
        // Set response content type
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Actual logic goes here.
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>" + ProcessData.getStatus() + "</h1>");
    }
}
```

After this the ProcessData class which implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
This listener has method which will be executed when web application initialization process is starting.

```
public class ProcessData implements ServletContextListener
{
    private static String message;
    private int counter = 0;

    Runnable run = new Runnable()
   {
        @Override
        public void run()
       {
            message = "counter: " + (counter++);
            System.out.println(message);
       }
   };

   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0)
   {
       ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(run, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
   }

   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0)
   {
       // Empty method
   }

   public static String getStatus()
   {
       return message;
   } 
}
```

And the web.xml add the servlet and also ServletContextListener like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>TestTask</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

   <listener>
         <listener-class>schedule.ProcessData</listener-class>
   </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I ask before why you need to inject it because if you have a task which is not connected with specific user (like yours is executed regardless if the user is logon or not) then you end up in situation that many users need access to a single data. You need some kind of singleton and yes you can do it with CDI beans or other Injection technology but you also can make it working without this overhead. In my example I do it with static method and static field.

Comment: If you definitely want to use some injection from Jave EE I suggest you to look at CDI: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html and here is one article which can help you: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/does_cdi_injection_of_sessionscoped